# Excel: Calculate pilot currencies

Tags: microsoft-excel, calculator

I recently got my pilots license and started using Microsoft Excel as my backup logbook. Now I'd like to add a "currency-calculator", which should show me until when I am type and day/night current based on my landings.

So the rule here and pretty much around the world is that your currency counts from your

> "third last landing PLUS 90 days"

(or officially spoken a pilot keeps current whenever (s)he is doing 3 takeoffs and landings within the 90 days, but I focus on landings only as I always do the takeoffs).

To make things even more complicated, there are different currencies, which means I need to keep track of staying aircaft type current (C150, C152, and C172) as well as DAY and NIGHT current.

Please have a look at following screenshot (download link see below), which is a cut down version of my big excel logbook. As you will see I have different flights with different amount of landings per flight.
[image]

My problem to solve **WITHOUT using vba**: calculate until when I am current on the aircraft type and day/night as shown in the screenshot (the two bottom parts)

You can also download the excel file from here: http://wikisend.com/download/445380/Example.xlsx

Many thanks for all your help and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, this was a fun one...   I came up with a solution, but you'd have to add some helper columns...  The "3rd last" logic is the tough part.
[image]

Columns F-H calculate how many landings of the same type/day/night have occurred since this date (including this date).

The Current Until formulas take the last date where the "landings since" is greater than 2 (i.e. giving us the 3rd last date, if I understand it correctly) and adds 90 days.

Note:  You'll have to un-merge the Current Until cells in order to make the array formulas.

EDIT:  Modified example file @ http://wikisend.com/download/104930/Example-solution.xlsx

Comment: Hi MadBall, yes, I agree, it is a tricky one, I normally don't need much help in Excel, but as you said the "third last" is the big trick.
Your answer looks correct so far, any chance of uploading the file to a temporary space like http://wikisend.com/ ? (No sign up required)

Comment: Done, and answer edited.

Comment: Cheers mate, I think it is correct, will fully verify tonight and if correct give you the correct answer tick. :-)

Comment: Genius! I verified it and works exactly as requested, well done mate! :-) Thank you.

Comment: I know this is solved but the principle intrigued me: I thought there might be a way to employ the lesser used LARGE function, which can find the Nth largest value (in this case, 3rd). This array function (enter with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) seems to generate the names you need in C14:C16: =LARGE(IF((C6:C11=B14),B6:B11),3)+90

Comment: @Gary:  Cool idea, and actually the tact I took originally.  Unfortunately, the requirements require us to find the date of 3 landings back, which is not necessarily the same as 3 dates back...